# Prevent Thumb Dragging in Certain Regions

Tags: silverlight

Below is a very crude start to a thumb template that eventually might look like a respectable popup window.  Obviously the user can drag it around from any location therein.  Is there any way to make it so it can *only* be dragged from the top AliceBlue border?  Put another way, it is possible to disable dragging from the second border?

```
    <Popup x:Name="MyPopup">
        <Popup.Child>
            <Thumb DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta">
                <Thumb.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="20">
                            <Border Height="20" Width="200" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,2,2,0" CornerRadius="3,3,0,0" Background="AliceBlue"></Border>
                            <Border Height="200" Width="200" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2" Background="Bisque"></Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Thumb.Template>
            </Thumb>
        </Popup.Child>
    </Popup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this so it's a bit of a guess.  Add an event handler to the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event on AliceBlue `Border`.  In the event handler:-

```
e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: You meant to say add it to the *Bisque* border, but, no matter, that worked perfectly.  Thank you much!